# Creating a Milestone for a Github Project via REST

Tags: rest, github, github-api

I would like to use the REST API of Github to manage the milestones and labels of some of my repositories, but I constantly fail to create new milestones or labels via REST. What do I miss?

I enable 2FA for my account and also create a personal access token, as it is described in [Other Authentication Methods](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/)

For example I try to create a new milestone with this cURL command:

```
curl -X POST -v \
  -H "Authorization: token MyPersonalAccessToken" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -d '{"title": "1", "state": "open", "description": "Milestone", "due_on": "2025-10-09T23:39:01Z"}' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/obfischer/boxsack/milestones
```

I tried various other variants but all seems to be wrong. At least I always get only a `404 Not Found`. According to the Github documentation this could also mean that my authentication failed, as Github returns a `404 Not Found` response code to protect user data instead of returning a `401 Unauthorized`.

But I am pretty sure that the authentication via the Person Access Token is working as I can see a user specific rate-limit headers in the response:

```
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999
```

Does someone have a clue why I can't create a milestone via REST?

Comment: maybe your personnal access token doesn't have the [repo scope](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/). I've just tested to send the request with a token without that scope & it also returns 404

Comment: You might be right. The response contains the header `X-OAuth-Scopes`, which is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your personal access token doesn't have the [repo scope](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/). I've just tested to send the request with a token without that scope & it also returns 404 :

```
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Sat, 26 Oct 2019 11:07:31 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 125
< Server: GitHub.com
< Status: 404 Not Found
< X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
< X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4989
< X-RateLimit-Reset: 1572091544
< X-OAuth-Scopes: [Here there should be repo] <================
< X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: 
< X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; format=json
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
< X-Frame-Options: deny
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: 87B2:23EED:36F2B7F:42647AE:5DB428F3
< 
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/milestones/#create-a-milestone"
}
```